# Python regex split PL/SQL instructions

Tags: python, regex, plsql

I am trying to split PL/SQL intructions. I came with following pattern:

```
splitter_re = '(DECLARE.+?END;)\n+|;\n+'
```

And I have following PL/SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE bk_temp1_kb AS
SELECT DISTINCT bk_c, bk_o, bk_r, bk_m
FROM www2013_02;


DECLARE
  time_val NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT day INTO time_val
  FROM days
  WHERE day_desc = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1);

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'DROP TABLE telep';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'CREATE TABLE telep AS
  SELECT cc,
       dao,
       a,
       nam     
  FROM prodc
  WHERE timer = ' || time_val;
END;


DROP TABLE kart;

CREATE TABLE kart AS
SELECT b.dwp
FROM t_prod_new b
WHERE b.task = 'CARD';
```

The result of the split() is:

```
['CREATE TABLE bk_temp1_kb AS\nSELECT DISTINCT bk_c, bk_o, bk_r, bk_m\nFROM www2
013_02', None, '', "DECLARE\n  time_val NUMBER;\nBEGIN\n  SELECT day INTO time_v
al\n  FROM days\n  WHERE day_desc = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1);\n \n  EXECUTE IMMEDIAT
E\n  'DROP TABLE telep';\n \n  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE\n  'CREATE TABLE telep AS\n  SE
LECT cc,\n       dao,\n       a,\n       nam     \n  FROM prodc\n  WHERE timer =
 ' || time_val;\nEND;", 'DROP TABLE kart', None, "CREATE TABLE kart AS\nSELECT b
.dwp\nFROM t_prod_new b\nWHERE b.task = 'CARD';"]
```

And it is quite nice, but I have None elements. What is wrong with pattern?

Comment: Your regex is not working. What happens if I have a table, say, named "send"?

Comment: I have to ask, why? Don't create tables in PL/SQL it's an indication of bad database design more than anything else. It also does an implicit commit in the session, which can confuse matters a lot. Secondly if you're trying to parse this with Python there must be a good reason to do so. It'd be easier not to.

Comment: It's just an example. I have many others that include normal SQL instructions and DECLARE ... END; This is my main problem, not SQL code itself.

Comment: SQL is not a regular language. Trying to parse it with regular expressions is doomed to failure.

Comment: [sqlparse](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/) might work.

Answer (score 0):

You have None elements because you have groups made by `()` which do not have content

```
'(x)|y' 
matches "x" with ("x", ...)
matches "y" with (None, ...)
```

because the first `(x)` has no match

change

```
'(DECLARE.+?END;)\n+|;\n+'
```

to

```
'(?:DECLARE.+?END;)\n+|;\n+'
```

to remove the None.

```
(?:x)|y
is the same as
x|y
```

the brackets do not group then

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but with this fix, I am loosing my whole DECLARE...END; expression.

Comment: How is `'(?:DECLARE.+?END;)\n+'`

Comment: Could you please give me some advice? I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: `result = [x for x in result if x]`

Comment: The real problem is as @Wooble said: this language can not be parsed by regular expressions. only in most of the cases. Sometimes you may not know what `end` belongs to.